# Restore previous Preview in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

New Preview for layout in Android Studio is really annoying, basically because when I want to zoom in preview and move, I have to use additional button with hand in icon, instead of drag and drop. Is it possible to restore old preview without downgrading Android Studio?

[image: New Preview]

Comment: the only way is to use the older AS